# Loading large csv file by altering tablespace

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I am loading a large csv file (>1.5G) in Oracle on my laptop. And some error came out saying "ORA-01653: table SYSTEM.CTS can't pass 1024 (in tablespace SYSTEM ) extend."

I know I can fix it by using code like:

```
alter tablespace SYSTEM add datafile 'XXX' size 2000m;
```

My questions are:

(1) What should XXX be in my code? I am loading file using sqlldr, and here is my ctl file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\...cts.csv'
APPEND
INTO TABLE cts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
   Tdate,
   Symbol,
   Topen,
   Thigh,
   Tlow,
   Tclose,
   Tvolume
)
```

(2) Is the size 2000m enough please?

Comment: You'd insert the desired datafile path into the `XXX`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Should XXX be my "..../../cts.csv" please? Where should I put this alterspace statement please?

Comment: Nope that should be the location/name of the new datafile you plan on creating. This (I don't believe) would go into SQL Loader it would be executed on the DB before you run your loads. Basically it is telling you there isn't enough room for you to load your data so you have to add room for it to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little bit confused. If I am to insert into a table cts. Should XXX be my table name please?

Comment: It would probably be better to have a separate tablespace for your own data, separate from the internal data in the system tablespace. You don't really want something you're doing to cause a space issue for the database itself.

Comment: @AlexPoole is right. You don't increase the size of a table, you are increasing the size of the tablespace it goes into.

Comment: `xxx` is going to be the full path to a file on the operating system, it's not related to your table name. A tablespace is a logical unit of space, which is made up of one or more physical data files. A table takes up some of the space in the logical tablespace.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is clear. Where should I run this alter tablespace statement please? In ctl file? or in command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the SYSTEM tablespace by adding another datafile. In the place of your 'XXX' should be the location of your new datafile, for instance:

```
alter tablespace SYSTEM add datafile 'C:\oracle\OracleHome\oradata\orcl\extra_system.dbf' size 2000m;
```

I would think 2000m would be enough for a 1,5G file, but you might want to put a little extra in there, considering it's the SYSTEM tablespace.

It is probably wise to put your own data in a seperate tablespace btw, and not in SYSTEM. This way you have seperate datafiles for SYSTEM and your personal applications, which means you can more easily move your own stuff to a larger harddrive, or back them up. This is also more secure and managable, because you don't have to use a user that can alter the SYSTEM tablespaces.

EDIT: The datafile is a file used by Oracle to store its data. All data inside the database will be stored inside these types of files, in the Oracle installation directory (typically). You can see the name of the current SYSTEM datafiles by using this query:

```
SELECT  FILE_NAME, BLOCKS, TABLESPACE_NAME
FROM DBA_DATA_FILES
WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'SYSTEM';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I don't know what is datafile.  If I want to insert into a table cts. Should XXX be my table name please? Where should I put this alter statement? Should it be in the ctl file?

Comment: It does not relate to the .CTL file at all. This problem is caused by the database running out of disk space it is able to use. I have added a short explanation of what the datafiles are for in the answer, and a query to see the current filenames of the SYSTEM datafiles. You should probably put the new datafile in the same folder as one of the existing ones, but with a different name.